# SQL Insert multi rows from multi list values

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I am trying to insert records into a SQL 2008 R2 table where the values being inserted vary.

```
<cftry>    
    <cfquery name="AddListMembers" datasource="HHSCIntra">    
       INSERT INTO tbl_MailMembers (DateEntered, EnteredBy, Method,Member,List)    
       VALUES (
          CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
          , '#session.UserID#'
          , 'A'
          , '#session.RecipientDistinguishedName#'
          , '#session.DistListDistinguishedName#'
       )
    </cfquery>
    <cfcatch type="Database">
       <cfoutput>#cfcatch.message#</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>    
</cftry>
```

The values that vary are `session.RecipientDistinguishedName` and `session.DistListDistinguishedName`, all of the other values are constant. Basically one time I might be

- Adding 3 members to 1 distribution list, or
- Adding 1 member to 4 distribution lists, or
- Adding 3 members to 5 distribution lists

I've tried a number of loop combinations but all I get is one record written to the table: the first member in the list and the first distribution list.

**UPDATE:**

OK things have changed a bit, we're only allowing users to work on one distribution list at a time. So below what I have now. (Please note I left out cfqueryparam and some other details so things would fit better in the post.)

```
<cfloop list="#session.RecipientDistinguishedName#" index="i" delimiters="">
   <cfquery name="AddListMembers" datasource="HHSCIntra">
      INSERT INTO tbl_MailMembers (DateEntered, EnteredBy, Method, Member, List)
      VALUES (
         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
         , '#session.UserID#'
         , 'A'
         , '#i#'
         , '#session.DistListDistinguishedName#'
      )
   </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

In the code where I pull the employee distinguished name from AD, I added this:

```
<cfinput type="hidden" name="frmEmpDistinguishedName"
        value="#EmployeeAdd.distinguishedName#;">
```

The semi colon is added to the end of the distinguished name so that I can use that as a separator when I query that table. So what ends up in the column `Member` is a long string containing all the distinguished name separated by a semi-colon.

One thing I have noticed is the first distinguished name in the column starts out as `CN=`, but all subsequent distinguished names start out `,CN=`. I'm playing around with querying that table to see if that's going to be a problem. Any suggestions on better ways of doing this would be appreciated.

**FINAL UPDATE:::**

I removed the `;` from the `cfinput` tag, and added the code below
before the cfloop in the insert query. Now I'm getting on long string of multiple distinguished names, separated by a semi-colon in the column `Member`.

```
<cfset session.RecipientDistinguishedName="#Replace(session.RecipientDistinguishedName,'DC=org,','DC=org;','ALL')#">
```

Comment: first, you need to learn how to use `<cfqueryparam>`, then you need to learn `<cfloop>`, then wrap `<cfquery>` with it.

Comment: where's your attempt to insert multiple records?

Comment: *I've tried a number of loop combinations* Please post that code [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30471574/edit) (rather than as an "answer").

Comment: Sorry Leigh, I had the code on there, but I deleted it, because we are only going to allow users to work on one distribution list at a time. I've got the insert query working that way, but it's putting all the members  distinguishedNames in one long string in the Member column instead of a new row for each member distinguishedName. I'll work on it some more tomorrow then post what I have.

Comment: (Edit) @toleolu - Okay, but my point was that we need to *see* the actual code causing the problem. Instead of "describing" the code, just post it ;-) However, I see you did that now.  *it's putting all the members distinguishedNames in one long string*  As you guessed (in your deleted answer) you are probably using the wrong list delimiter in your loop. Please update your question with an example of the `DistListDistinguishedName` value and the desired results.

Comment: Thanks again Leigh, I posted the fix above where I added the cfset tag to do a replace changing dc=org to dc=org; used the semi colon as my delimiter and now I'm getting each record on a separate row.

Comment: Sounds good.  Though a tip for next time - be sure to include an example of the "list" (if needed obfuscate the names to protect the innocent). You would have gotten an answer much faster had the question included all of the relevant info from the start ;-)  Usually that means 1) Smallest [repro case](http://www.sscce.org/) possible 2) Sample data values if applicable 3) Brief description of actual vs expected results and 4) Any error messages. Since you figured it out, pat yourself on the back and post the final code as an "answer" for the next guy :)

Answer (score 1):

With sql server you can use this construct.

```
<cfquery>
insert into yourTable
(field1, field2, etc)
select null, null, etc
where 1 = 2
<cfloop>
union 
select value1, value2, etc
</cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

I'll leave the details to you.  Pay attention to Henry's comment about query parameters.